# positioning a div directly below an image of unknown size

Tags: css, html

I have an image that is meant to take up the whole screen horizontally, so it looks like this

```
<img src="location" id="banner" style="width: 100%" />
```

is there a way to determine the pictures height? I need to place a div container directly below it using an absolute position.

Comment: You could set the height

Comment: no, sorry, I should have mentioned that the height and width ratio needs to be maintained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a wrapper and position the element 100% from the top.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="location" id="banner" style="width: 100%" />
    <div id="positioned">testing</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#positioned {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
```

A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmh3s/) example.

Answer (score 0):

add a reference to jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

add this script

```
<script>
var imgHeight = $("#banner").height();
</script>
```

Comment: how would I use that variable in the HTML code later?

Comment: You wouldn't, you would use Jquery something like =("#divId").property and change whatever property or style of the element, in your case a div I guess

Comment: You wouldn't, you would use Jquery something like =("#divId").property and change whatever property or style of the element,so like we got the  height, we could just set the height like this $("#banner").height= or in native JS you could do document.getElementById("div").style.height = 100 + imgHeight;

Answer (score 0):

Only use `position:absolute;` for below-div and do not give any `top` or `bottom` value.